# Официальная аббревиатура Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: обсуждение, термины, stackoverflow

Название основного сайта этой сети часто сокращают до аббревиатуры `SO`. Предлагаю выработать краткое название для этого сайта.
[Похожий вопрос есть на англоязычной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51945/what-is-the-accepted-cool-kid-abbreviation-for-stackoverflow)

Comment: не обязательно протоколировать всё на свете

Answer (score 12):

В установлении *официальной* аббревиатуры я не вижу смысла. Каждый вправе писать, как хочет. Однако, есть статистически предпочитаемые варианты.

- ru.SO, Ru.SO
- pt.SO, Pt.SO
- Англоязычный сайт:

  - en.SO, En.SO или SO при употреблении на локализованном сайте
  - SO на самом SO и на других сайтах сети.

В чате вариант "ru.so" [употреблялся 147 раз](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=ru.so&user=&room=22462), без учёта регистра, a "en.so" - [62 раза](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=en.so&user=&room=22462).

Участники, использующие этот вариант, в разных регистрах: Nofate, Vlad, Tagir Valeev, cyadvert, Abyx, Nick Volynkin, Dmitriy Simushev, alexander barakin, andreycha, VenZell,avp, soon, igumnov, Andrey Bakharev/BOPOH, Yura Ivanov, eicto, PashaPash, LEQUADA, Athari/Discord, TheDoctor, Nicolas Chabanovsky, J.F.Sebastian.

Вне сайта: [nicael](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252518/296059)

Я предпочитаю регистр именно как в "Ru.SO", потому что первая часть соответствует первым двум буквам имени языка в нормальном их написании, а вторая соответствует принятой аббревиатуре ("SO", но не "so").

Однако, похоже, более популярным является вариант со строчным регистром в локали: ru.SO.

Comment: Только Вы совсем не обратили внимание, что некоторые участники (и я тоже) пишут все же **ru.SO** (а не ru.so или Ru.SO)

Comment: @avp верно, спасибо за поправку. Дополню ответ.

Comment: ru.so - даёшь FIDO :-) хотя я пишу тоже ru.SO

Comment: @MonahTuk а почему в FIDO именно так?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я не помню, но по логике: так парсить проще человеку - сразу видно языковую принадлежность эхоконференции. Кстати, в usenet тоже так принято.

Answer (score 7):

- ruSO
- enSO

Употребление в чате: ["ruSO" 21 раз](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=ruso&user=&room=22462), ["enSO" 30 раз](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=enso&user=&room=22462).

Answer (score 1):

Внутри компании мы используем следующие аббревиатуры.

- Stack Overflow - SO (он же SOen).
- Meta Stack Overflow - MSO (он же MSOen).
- Meta Stack Exchange - MSE.
- Stack Overflow на русском (in Russian) - SOru.
- Мета Stack Overflow на русском (in Russian) - MSOru.
- Stack Overflow на любом языке - SO*.

Comment: Для людей со стороны аббревиатуры MSE и MSO, имеют, скорее, другие значения (первые предлагаемые Google варианты связаны с Microsoft).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, конкретные названия я специально не указывал ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: удалил подсказку )

Answer (score -2):

Russian Stack Overflow == Ru.St.Ovf. == "RuStOff"
Русский "Стек Оверфлоу" == Ру.Ст.Овф. == "РуСтОфф"

Всё сходится...  =)

Comment: Слишком уж долго набирать, тем более с разным регистром.

Answer (score -4):

`ru.st` - по начальным символам адреса домена `ru.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Можно перепутать с языком программирования Rust.

Comment: Нельзя. Про него никто не знает

Comment: @banme это смотря где.